# Do casters know target's HD when they cast Cause Fear?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, targeting

[Cause Fear](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/causeFear.html) says:

> **Target** one living creature with 5 or fewer HD

This implies the caster cannot target anybody with Hit Dice bigger than 5. Does that mean they actually knows if the creature had 5 or fewer HD? Or they actually can target such a creature, thus, waste the spell?

Comment: [Relevant](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51832/8610), as is [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63677/8610) and [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60466/8610).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The typical creature doesn't know (and usually can't determine) another creature's Hit Dice

A few rare special abilities *can* [determine a creature's hit points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77138/8610), but determining a creature's Hit Dice is rarer still, usually coming down to just guesswork. (Perhaps a generous GM will allow a creature's typical Hit Dice to be learned as a hint with a successful [Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge/) skill check to gain some monster lore about the creature, but that's subject to the GM's whims.)

To summarize, [Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) on [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) says, "Some spells have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself." However, on [Spell Failure](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Spell-Failure) says, "If you ever try to cast a spell in conditions where the characteristics of the spell cannot be made to conform, the casting fails and the spell is wasted." Casting a spell on an invalid target is one of these cases that wastes an otherwise perfectly good spell.

Further, according to [Saving Throws](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Saving-Throw) on Succeeding on a Saving Throw, a caster knows when "a creature’s saving throw succeeds against a targeted spell[, and, because of the target's successful saving throw, the caster knows] that the spell has failed." But when the target is simply—for whatever reason—flat-out *immune* to the spell, the caster receives *no* feedback from the spell.

So when a caster that casts a spell on an invalid target—like, for example, a caster that casts the spell [*cause fear*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cause-fear/) on a 6 Hit Dice foe—, the caster *won't* know that the spell failed nor will the caster know *why* the spell doesn't appear to be having the effect it's supposed to have.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't know a target's HD in any case. The GM may handwave this as 'intuition', however. In general though, no you don't. The spell is wasted on higher HD creatures.