# How can a creature's maximum hp be determined?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, knowledge-check

Is it possible to determine a creature's **maximum hit points** through a Knowledge skill check or another means?

---

Related: [What check to use for finding out current hit points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/what-check-to-use-for-finding-out-current-hit-points)

Comment: Comments on an answer to the linked question already list the slayer talent [**blood reader**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/slayer/slayer-talents/paizo-slayer-talents/blood-reader/) as doing what this question asks. Are you looking for all the things like that?

Comment: That is current, which is generally much harder to find. I am specifically referring to maximum and if that can be determined through a knowledge check

Comment: Cool. I did a quick edit on this so other folks wouldn't miss the word *maximum*. Also, I'm curious: What does your character want this information for?

Comment: Specifically for spells like power word kill or power word stun. If you can get maximum you can know if you can use it off the bat.

Comment: …But a caster gleans whether or not a *power word* spell is useful based on the creature's **current** hp (see, for example, [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/power-word-kill/)). That is, for this purpose of *power word* spells, knowing a creature's *maximum* hp is worse information than knowing the creature's *current* hp. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HeyICanChan by "use it off the bat", I think they want to know if there's situations they can get the max HP, but not the current, and use that to decide whether they should just PW:K the enemies or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not through a knowledge check.

The rules for the knowledge skill states:

> You can use this skill to identify monsters and their special powers or vulnerabilities.

The maximum possible number of hit points a monster has is neither a *special* power (e.g., breath weapon, spell casting, shape shift) nor is it a vulnerability (e.g., susceptible to sunlight, extra damage from fire attacks). All monsters have hit points, so there's nothing "special" about them from an objective standpoint. A GM might give you a clue to the monster's general toughness from a successful knowledge check, but knowing specifically the maximum hit points a particular type of monster can have is beyond the scope of the Knowledge skill.

There are no other official skills, feats, spells, special abilities or magic items that reveal maximum hit points of a monster type.

### You could always check the *Bestiary*.

Not to be flippant, but if you're going to be so meta as to calculate the maximum possible number of hit points a monster has to determine whether your character will cast a certain spell, you might as well just check the *Bestiary* if the GM allows it. If the GM does *not* allow it then that tells you something: he is seeking to limit the amount of meta information available to you at the table, and the general reason for this is to maintain an air of mystery and uncertainty for the player and simulate a lack of information available to the player character. GM's generally do this to enhance the fun of the game--the idea being that it's fun to have some uncertainty when you face a monster. The point here being that this is likely information the GM doesn’t want you to have ready access to, but if he does, then he probably won’t mind you consulting the *Bestiary*.

### Your best bet for determining if a *Power Word* spell is worth casting, if you have time, is the use of an *augury* spell.

If a wizard is considering *Power Word Kill* or *Power Word Stun*, as you state in the comments, having a cleric cast *augury* and asking about that course of action should yield a solid answer as to whether or not it will be effective. This is not a way to find out a monster type's max hit points, but it does address that specific problem.